# Map Vs Filter Operations

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, mapreduce

In the 1st line of the 2nd paragraph, Wiki (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce) says that map() shall be responsible for "Filtering" as well.

Whereas, my understanding was this that map() shall be ONLY responsible for changing the "Form" of the data set through "Transformation", and not for "Filtering".

Is that line confusing ?

Comment: Map is a very general term that can mean multiple things. As that is the wiki for `MapReduce`, I'm assuming this means that when working with Hadoop, the map stage is something bigger then running a `map()` function in Spark, it is the entire processing a single unit of work.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But as a matter of fact that Spark also leverages "MapReduce Framework", so I was wondering that how about executing  business specific filtering logic through Spark map() method ?

Comment: That's not how it works with Spark. There is no logical separation between a big map stage and a reduce stage (unlike MapReduce which requires you to persist any output of a Map stage to read it from the Reduce). A spark job contains a set of transformations you apply to a distributed data set. One of those transformations can be a `filter` transformation.

Comment: I can see now, that unlike MapReduce(as an example,Hadoop Job-Tracker), Spark "driver manager" allows parallel execution of "map() & reduce functions, across worker nodes. MapReduce, doesn't support this style of map()/reduce() execution. Instead, MapReduce finishes map()-stage first and then switch over to "reduce_stage". Interestingly, in future, Spark shall also support this style of "grouped reduce()" execution, with the help of "shuffle() transformation (refer#https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~franklin/Papers/hotcloud.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding pure map-reduce (which this wiki refers to), filtering in the map stage is the way to go:

- you have no preprocessing *before* the map-stage
- you should reduce data as much as possible to lighten the data load on the shuffle-and-sort stage
- thus, *map* is the place to apply business logic filtering as far as you need it

Basically, as you only implement map and reduce, you might also interpret this as: *Given the stages map and reduce, perform business filtering in _map_, as filtering in _reduce_ would send much unnecessary data through the cluster.*

Hope that makes it clearer.

*Edit, after the comment referencing spark.*

Note, that the map()-function in the spark streaming API is totally different from the map-function in map-reduce.

It is just unfortunate coincidence, that they are called the same, as spark layers a stream-like API over the map-reduce (or yarn) complexity, which traditionally has a map()-function which is a concept from functional programming. That map-function also does not have anything along the lines of an emit-step.

Thus: map in map-reduce (where there are *no other functions* apart from map and reduce - check the examples in the link you posted) shall do filtering. Note that the map in map-reduce has 0 .. n outputs for each single input.

Map in spark or other kinds streaming API shall do just transformations from one type to another. (One input leads to one output.)

Comment: That sounds right in context to Hadoop. But in case of Spark, where we have Method: filter(), exclusively for filtering, business logic for filtering should go inside it.

Comment: Regarding *no other functions* in mapreduce, according to the wiki, there is partition and compare

Comment: Those are part of the shuffle-and-sort stage and not part of the basic map-reduce programming approach. Especially, as they come after the mapping stage, they are not suited to perform filtering on the data.

Answer (score 1):

**Map**, you pass in a function which returns a value for each element in an array. The return value of this function represents `what an element becomes in our new array`.

**Filter**, you pass in a function which returns either true or false for each element. If the function that you pass returns true for an element, then `that element is included in the final array`.